# Collapsible sidebar with the Semantic-UI framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to make a sidebar using [Semantic-UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) which, when collapsed, still has a portion visible. Something like [this](http://rdash.github.io/#/), to be more precise. I have tried looking in the semantic-ui css source, hoping to find something that might be of help, unfortunately, I couldn't find anything that could be useful.

Is there any possible way of doing it using semantic, without having to write the whole sidebar javascript/css from scratch?  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi @AndyM and Carjan Radu-Liviu, did you get this implemented?
I am trying to achieve something quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436385/semantic-ui-sidebar-with-icons-always-visible
A sidebar with labelled icons, where in collapsed state, the sidebar narrows and leaves the icons visible...

Comment: Hello, @Windwalker. Yes, I actually managed to get this implemented. Please see my answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the `sidebar` component is for. See examples here: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples