# Semantic-UI: Sidebar with Icons always visible

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'd like to implement a sidebar, where each entry will have an Icon along to it's text.

In deactivated state, the sidebar shall display only the icons, wheres in activated state, the sidebar shall expand to its whole width, showing its entries with both icons and text.
Just like the *menu* button in [Expanding Menu Button](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html), but this behaviour for the whole sidebar.

Can this be done using Semantic UI?

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable solution? I am looking for the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a similar question a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699420/collapsible-sidebar-with-the-semantic-ui-framework), and I managed to solve it myself, by modifying some of Semantic-UI's source code.

Unfortunately, the modifications were too extensive to post them directly in this answer, so I have created a github repo with an example [here](https://github.com/rcarjan/semantic-sidebar). Hopefully it helps. Due to the fact that the source code from Semantic-UI was modified, normal sidebars will probably be buggy.

Comment: I'm not sure modifying semantic itself is a good solution. I have the same problem and I'm just thinking to not use semantic for that component and just write my own.